# How to read TZipFile.FileComment as a string?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

When you try to read a TZipFile.FileComment the compiler reports that this will not compile:
[dcc64 Error] Unit1.pas(451): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'System.TArray'

```
var
  iFileComment: string;
...
iFileComment := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].FileComment;
```

So... how do you read a TZipFile comment and assign it to a string?  This seems strange because I can successfully write the zipfile comment as follows:

```
iZipFile.FileComment[ListView1.ItemIndex] := FileComment1.Text;
```

If you try to read the comment with:

```
iFileComment := iZipFile.FileComment[i];
```

every file in the zip file has the same comment, even though only one file actually has a filecomment.

The comments are added by this:

```
procedure TForm1.SetFileComment1Click(Sender: TObject); var  
iZipFile: TZipFile;   iListItem: TlistItem; 
begin   
  if ListView1.ItemIndex <> -1 then   
  begin
     iZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
     try
       { Open zip file for writing }
       iZipFile.Open(ZipFilename1.Text, zmReadWrite);
       iZipFile.FileComment[ListView1.ItemIndex] := FileComment1.Text;
       { Close the zip file }
       iZipFile.Close;
       { Update the listview }
       ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
       try
         iListItem := ListView1.Items.Item[ListView1.ItemIndex];
         iListItem.SubItems[5] := FileComment1.Text;
       finally
         ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
       end;
     finally
       iZipFile.Free;
     end;   
  end   
  else   
  begin
    MessageBox(0, 'A filename is not selected. Please select a filename.',
       'Warning', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
  end; 
end;
```

**EDIT**

I am now setting and writing the filecomments with iZipFile.FileComment[Index] as suggested.
When I set one file's comment and open the zip file in a working zip app only the single file that I set appears with the comment... In this TZipFile project when I load the same zip file, every file has the same comment but I can not see why.  All the other fields operate as you would expect except for the filecomment field.

Here is the code that opens the zip file:

```
procedure TForm1.Open1Click(Sender: TObject);
{ Open zip file. }
var
  i: integer;
  iZipFile: TZipFile;
  iFilename: string;
  iDateTime: TDateTime;
  iCompressedSize: cardinal;
  iUnCompressedSize: cardinal;
  iCRC32: cardinal;
  iCompressionMethod: word;
  iFileComment: string;
  iListItem: TlistItem;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    if FileExists(OpenDialog1.FileName) then
    begin
      iZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
      try
        ListView1.Items.Clear;
        ZipFilename1.Text := OpenDialog1.FileName;
        try
          { Open zip file for reading }
          iZipFile.Open(ZipFilename1.Text, zmReadWrite);
          for i := 0 to iZipFile.FileCount - 1 do
          begin
            iFilename := iZipFile.FileNames[i];
            iListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
            iListItem.Caption := iFilename;
            iDateTime := FileDateToDateTime
              (iZipFile.FileInfo[i].ModifiedDateTime);
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(DateTimeToStr(iDateTime)); { 0 }
            iCompressedSize := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].CompressedSize;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(FormatByteSize(iCompressedSize)); { 1 }
            iUnCompressedSize := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].UncompressedSize;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(FormatByteSize(iUnCompressedSize)); { 2 }
            iCRC32 := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].CRC32;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(iCRC32)); { 3 }
            iCompressionMethod := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].CompressionMethod;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add
              (ZipCompressionToStr(iCompressionMethod)); { 4 }
            iFileComment := iZipFile.FileComment[i];
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(iFileComment); { 5 }
          end;
          { Close the zip file }
          iZipFile.Close;
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            ShowMessage(E.ClassName + #10#13 + E.Message);
          end;
        end;
      finally
        iZipFile.Free;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read it back the same way you write it, in reverse:

```
// Write the comment
iZipFile.FileComment[Index] := 'This is a zip file comment';

// Read it back
sComment := iZipFile.FileComment[Index];
WriteLn(sComment);             // Outputs "This is a zip file comment"
```

`Index` would match the index of the individual file within the zip archive. In other words, the first file would be at index 0, the second at index 1, etc., wit the last being at index `FileCount - 1`.

Here's a working example. I created a dummy zip file named `Test.zip` containing a few old .png files I've used in answers here (as seen in the image below):

[image: List of files in zip displayed in Windows Explorer]

I then used the below code to add comments to each file and read them back, writing them to the console:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Zip;

var
  Zip: TZipFile;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Zip := TZipFile.Create;
  Zip.Open('D:\TempFiles\Test.zip', zmReadWrite);
  for i := 0 to Zip.FileCount - 1 do
    Zip.FileComment[i] := Format('This is file %d', [i]);
  Zip.Free;  // Flushes changes to disk automatically

  // Create a new instance, just to make it clear.
  Zip := TZipFile.Create;
  Zip.Open('D:\TempFiles\Test.zip', zmReadWrite);
  for i := 0 to Zip.FileCount - 1 do
    WriteLn(Zip.FileNames[i] + ':'#9 + Zip.FileComment[i]);
  Zip.Free;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Here's the output it produced:

[image: Screen capture of console output displaying file comments from code above]

Here's the zip file comments it added, as displayed in 7Zip:

[image: Screen capture of 7Zip window with zip file names and comments]

Comment: Thanks Ken... that what I wound up doing... but every file in the zip file has the same comment, even though only one file actually has a filecomment. At least it compiles now <grin>

Comment: @Bill: See my edited answer for working code that demonstrates.

Comment: thanks for the code.  I changed mine to do the same, but there is a problem with the filecomment field as all the files in the zip are loaded with the same comment, despite setting only one filecomment for one file.  See my edit that shows how I am opening the zip file... which now appears to be the problem.

Comment: @Bill: Don't know what to tell you, except to create a new test app, eliminate all of the extraneous stuff about the listview, and figure out what's going wrong. I've added an image of the individual file comments (added by my sample code above) as displayed in 7zip's GUI, which clearly shows that the individual files have individual comments.

Comment: Thanks Ken... will do.

Answer (score 4):

In XE2, `TZipHeader.FileComment` was declared as a `RawByteString`, which could be assigned directly to a `String` (using a typecast to avoid a compiler warning):

```
iFileComment := String(iZipFile.FileInfo[i].FileComment);
```

However, in XE4, `TZipHeader.FileComment` is declared as a `TBytes` instead.  You cannot directly assign a `TBytes` to a `String` (and vice versa), hense the compiler error.

If you look at the implementation of `TZipFile.GetFileComment()` in XE4, it uses `TZipFile.TBytesToString()` to convert the `TBytes` to a `String`.  `TZipFile.TBytesToString()` uses `SysUtils.TEncoding.GetString()` to do the actual conversion, using either codepage 65001 or 437 depending on the value of the `TZipFile.UTF8Support` property.

The correct way to get/set each file's comment is to use the `TZipFile.FileComments[]` property, like Ken demonstrates.  Not only does it handle the string<->byte conversions for you, but it also checks to make sure the zip is open before accessing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive this old question but none of the answers actually addresses the *every file in the zip file has the same comment* problem.

### The cause is a bug in `TZipFile.ReadCentralHeader`

When a zip file is opened `ReadCentralHeader` reads all the zip directory entries into an internal list of records but fails to clear the temporary record, being used to populate the list, between each entry.

In the case of the file comment `ReadCentralHeader` first reads the `FileCommentLength` value but if this value is zero then it doesn't set the value of the `FileComment` value which therefore retains the value of the previous entry.

A possible work around is to take the `FileCommentLength` value into account when reading the `FileComment[]` property:

```
Comment := Copy(ZipFile.FileComment[Index], 1, ZipFile.FileInfo[Index].FileCommentLength);
```